# Using SQLite3 in Windows 8 Javascript App

Tags: javascript, windows-8, sqlite, microsoft-metro

Building a Windows 8 application with JavaScript for the new Windows Store I stumbled on the lack of good data storage mechanisms.

I would like my app to use the SQLite3, but I cannot seem to make it work. Closest I can get is an error "Class not registered" when trying to access SQLite3 API through JavaScript.

If you made it work for your app, please share an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the SQLLite-WinRT project on github.  I haven't played with it but it's in my queue of things to try out.

https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT

Here's a tutorial:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

Comment: This is one of the 3 libraries I tried, including the official one from SQLite page, neither worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, following this tutorial gave me the best result, but app crashes on launch with "Class not registered" error. Using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Sorry not sure why - wish I could help more.  BTW, are you on Win8 RTM or preview?

Comment: Thanks @bryanmac. It's RTM Pro. If you do have a chance to test this out on your own setup, please leave a comment with results.

Comment: @PauliusUza as one of the authors of the do SQLite component, I'd be interested in any problems you're encountering. Could you open a ticket on Github?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works in javascript but in the C# version of using sqlite you have to add the dll to the root folder of your app and make sure that in its properties its set to: content--> copy always